# Concatenate files that end with a specific set of characters

Tags: regular-expression, ls, cat

I need to concatenate files whose names have a second to last character in the file name in the list of `acegik` and the last character as a `1`.

Do I need to use grep for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: `cat *[acegik]1 new_file`

Comment: Thank you so much, I am sorry and I will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
cat *[acegik]1 >  output.txt
```